# Set a fixed-size storage array in constructor

Tags: solidity, arrays

I was hoping this would work..

```
contract Test {

    uint[] private grid;
    uint width = 5;
    uint height = 10;

    constructor() { 
        grid = new uint[width * height];
    }
}
```

Ideally I would used a fixed-length array but set the size dynamically.
Otherwise I will have to hardcode the size into the contract which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this syntax:

```js
grid = new uint[](width * height);
```

I refactored your code and this works:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Test {

    uint[] public grid;
    uint constant width = 2;
    uint constant height = 3;
    uint constant MAX_ELEMENTS = width * height;
    uint currentIndex;

    constructor() { 
        grid = new uint[](MAX_ELEMENTS);
    }

    function addElement(uint element) public {
        // This will fail if someone tries to add more than MAX_ELEMENTS elements. Using `.push` would not fail, but would add more elements than MAX_ELEMENTS.
        grid[currentIndex] = element;
        ++currentIndex;
    }

    function getGrid() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return grid;
    }

}
```

Comment: just FYI -- this works with arrays of uints, thank you! But not with an array of structs :-/

Comment: Using this syntax is enough while declaring the array of struct: `User[5] users;`;

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your other concern, that it did not work with an array of struct, here is the way to do it (read the comments):

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    struct User {
        uint256 id;
        string name;
    }

    User[5] users;

    uint256 public userCount;

    function addUser(uint256 id, string calldata name) public {
        // Will revert if the userCount is greater than 5 since we declared the `users` array to be of size 5
        // The .push method does not work on this array either, since we declared it with a size of 5
        users[userCount++] = User(id, name);
    }

}
```

No need to manually assign an array of struct in the constructor. As long as you declare it in the storage like `User[5] users;` is enough.

For your grid example, it would look like this:

```js
contract Test {

    //uint[] public grid;
    uint public constant width = 2;
    uint public constant height = 3;
    uint public constant MAX_ELEMENTS = width * height;
    uint public currentIndex;

    Grid[MAX_ELEMENTS] public grids;

    struct Grid {
        uint256 index;
    }

    function addElement(uint element) public {
        // This will fail if someone tries to add more than MAX_ELEMENTS elements. Using `.push` would not fail, but would add more elements than MAX_ELEMENTS.
        grids[currentIndex] = Grid(element);
        ++currentIndex;
    }

    function getGrid() public view returns(Grid[MAX_ELEMENTS] memory) {
        return grids;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this answer misses the point of the question... if ```grid``` was a struct, and we had public vars for width and height, how can we declare the array of grids with MAX_ELEMENTS

Comment: I didn't know what properties would your Grid struct have, so I didn't create an example. But I updated the answer and created a `struct Grid` with a `uint256 index;` member as an example. Take a look.